# Remove item from list without rerender other items

Tags: reactjs

I have a big `<List>` component which contains many `<Item>` components. Each `<Item>` has a button to remove itself from the list.

```
type IItem = {
  id: number;
  onClickRemove?: () => void;
};

const initialList = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];

const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState<IItem[]>(initialList);

  const removeItem = (id: number) => () => {
    setList((prev) => prev.filter((v) => v.id !== id));
  };

  return list.map((v) => <Item id={v.id} onClickRemove={removeItem(v.id)} key={v.id} />);
};

const Item = (props: IItem) => {
  console.log(`Item #${props.id} rendered`);

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={props.onClickRemove}>
        Remove Item #{props.id}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Click remove and the item is removed, this works correctly. However this simple action is very slow with a large list because the other items also re rendered. From my understanding, use memo on `<Item>` and useCallback on its props React should skip re-render. I apply them to the code like this but still doesn't work

```
const List = () => {
  ...
  const removeItem = useCallback((id: number) => () => {
    ...
  }, []);
  ...
};

const Item = memo((props: IItem) => {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
const List = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState<IItem[]>(initialList);

  const removeItem = useCallback((id: number) => {
    setList((prev) => prev.filter((v) => v.id !== id));
  }, []);

  return list.map((v) => <Item id={v.id} onClickRemove={removeItem} key={v.id} />);
};

const Item = memo((props: IItem) => {
  console.log(`Item #${props.id} rendered`);

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => props.onClickRemove(props.id)}>
        Remove Item #{props.id}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
});
```